# Ubuntu 12.04 reboots during startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, reboot

I have a clean installation of 12.04 32bit on Dell Gx620 USFF.

When I switch on computer after few hours (when the computer is shut off), then computer reboots during startup. Ubuntu logo appears then restart, this is repeated few times and then system starts normally.

Strange this is that this happens only when computer is shut off for long time, when I shut off computer and then switch on, Ubuntu starts normally.

I made `memtest`, changed BIOS battery, tried clean installation and nothing helps.

Please see the log file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdfz6yni66y8npz/syslog).

Comment: I would start with going through the syslog. Open a terminal window, `sudo su -`, then go to /var/log/ and look at the files syslog, syslog.1, ... Each line in these files is preceded with date and time. Try to locate the time when the reboot took place and see what happens. Post excerpts here.

Comment: Alternatively to `sudo su -`, run `gksudo gedit /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Please find log bellow, this time I have about 5 reboots before ubuntu starts https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdfz6yni66y8npz/syslog

Comment: Can someone help me? Thanks, Petr